# How to add java library reference to a shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix

I have the following spring reference jars in a file springClasspath

```
    CLASSPATH=/apps/cab/spring/spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:/apps/cab/spring/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/apps/cab/spring/spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:/apps/cab/spring/spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar 
export CLASSPATH
```

I want to reference the springClasspath file to my shell script file start_order.sh for my java program to reference the required spring dependencies.How can I do so?

Comment: `springClasspath` is a separate file? and you want to use the variable `CLASSPATH` defined in it in your other script? What type of file is `CLASSPATH` does it have other lines than the variable initialization?

Comment: springClasspath is a seperate file. yes i want to use the CLASSPATH variable in other script also.springClasspath file contains only the library dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple declarations in the `springClasspath` file which you are planning to use in the shell script. You need it to `source` the file in the script to use the variables further.

By sourcing the file in the script, you are making the variables defined in it to be available in the sub-shell in which the script is being run from.  For example, in the `start_order.sh` line after setting the interpreter to `bash` source the script as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Give the full path to the file if it is present in another location
. ./springClasspath 

# with the above source done, the variables can be used as below in your
# script
echo "$CLASSPATH"
```

Remember `export`-ing the file won't work in this case, *unless* your source the file and *also* the script so that they run in the same parent shell with the variables set.